# AngularJS history manipulation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Normally with JavaScript you can use the following to manipulate the history, but it does not work.
Example: What I want to achieve is to go to /clients/:id and then when I go back, I want to go to /blog/, doesn't matter which page i was on before.

```
$scope.changeView = function(clientId){
  history.pushState({}, null, '/#/blog');
  $location.path('/client/' + clientId);
};
```

However, this does not work in Angular.

**Any idea how this could be solved?**

Answer (score 0):

As I am confused about what your question is.. (Are you just trying to find an Angular way of manipulating the history? Or are you trying to redirect?)

Something that may be of interest to you is the [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service on AngularJS.

I just used `history.pushState(), null, '/aboutus')` while on a page within my app, clicked a link, then went back and it seemed to load that '/aboutus' link just fine, so long as your Angular app is configured to route that path somewhere.

Comment: Edited the primary post, since I forgot to mention I do use $location also

Comment: When is $scope.changeView being called?